# Vue 3, scrollLeft not updating DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3

I'm having an issue where the squares container doesn't update its scrollLeft property. I'm trying to smoothly animate it by having it scroll to a specific "square" in the container. For example purposes, I only increment it by +1 (this code is obviously really bad but only for testing to show the problem). But it only moves after I stop updating scrollLeft, so in this case; after the loop is done. Almost seems like it's sync blocking. I tried nextTick or using a timeout but had no success.

```
<div class="squares-container" :scroll-left.camel="scrollLeft">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

```
this.$data.scrollLeft = 0;

const inter = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.$data.scrollLeft >= 1000) {
        clearInterval(inter);

        return;
    }

    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$data.scrollLeft += 1;
    });
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be caused by; scroll-behavior: smooth !important

Not entirely sure why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).